How are solid rocket propellants stored?
Unlike Liquid Propellants, solid propellants are already mixed with each other. I've always wondered, does that propellant ever go "bad"? and if it does, how do they prevent it from doing so?

related but not identical https://space.stackexchange.com/q/60991/26356

It doesn't "go bad" quickly if at all. Shuttle SRB segments were qualified for 5 year storage life and were successfully tested after 7 years. Minuteman III missiles were qualified for 10 years. Lots of fun reading at BIBLIOGRAPHY OF SOLID ROCKET COMPONENT AGING https://archive.org/details/DTIC_AD0372032/page/n11/mode/2up

Nitrocellulose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrocellulose is used as a component of some solid propellants. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-propellant_rocket#Composite_propellants But nitrocellulose was used as film base to make photographic film. This nitrate film was found to gradually decompose within some decades. "Many films produced during the early 20th century were lost through this accelerating, self-catalyzed disintegration". If solid propellants are used within less than 5 years the slow decomposition of nitrocellulose is no problem.

See https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/what-solid-fuel-was-used-in-the-katyushas-rocket-artillery-of-ww2?rq=1
